# Python - Filename validation help needed

Tags: python

Bad Filename Example:   `foo is-not_bar-3.mp4`
What it should be: `foo_is_not_bar-3.mp4`

I only want to keep a `-` for the last bit of the string if it is a digit followed by the extension. The closest I have gotten thus far is with the following code:

```
fname = 'foo is-not_bar-3.mp4'
valchars = '-_. %s%s' % (string.ascii_letters, string.digits)
f = ''.join(c for c in fname if c in valchars).replace(' ', '_').replace('-', '_')
```

Comment: what exactly is the issue?

Comment: @Rich Johnson import string

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex replacement with a negative lookahead:

```
import re

fname = 'foo is-not_bar-3.mp4'
f = re.sub(r'\s|-(?!\d+)', '_', fname)
print(f)
>> 'foo_is_not_bar-3.mp4'
```

This will replace every `-` and space with `_` **unless** it is followed by a number.

Comment: Answered before the coffee kicked in. Thanks a ton, this works out perfectly. I will use the re.sub after making sure there are valid chars & it works like a charm. Thanks!